# Determine the affected rows when sorting values in javascript, shell sort, insertion sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, sorting

I have these sorting algorithms in my application, and I want to keep track the affected values, or the values that swapped during the sorting process. I want to highlight them.

I have solved this issue for bubble sort and selection sort, but somehow I can't get it work with Insertion sort and shell sort.

Here is the fiddle of what I am trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/4jnXf/1/

As you can see, on the last part of the iteration, which is more likely like insertion sort, so I won't ask how to do it in insertion sort. The big problem is the first part, second part, third part of the iteration, because it makes no sense. And in the last part of the iteration. I does highlight too the values that don't swap.

How can I correct this. Thank you!
Here is the faulty code:

```
shell: function() {
    var list = anada.vars.$list;
    $.each(list, function(key, value){
        if (!isNaN(list[key])) {
            list[key] = parseInt(list[key]);
        } else {

        }
    });
    var n = list.length;
    var increment = Math.floor(n / 2);
    var i;
    while (increment > 0) {
        var unsorted = list;
        for (i = increment; i < n; i++) {
            var temp = list[i];
            var j = i;
            while (j >= increment && list[j - increment] > temp) {
                list[j] = list[j - increment];
                j -= increment;
            }
            list[j] = temp;
            var rows = '<tr>';
            for (ctr = 0; ctr < unsorted.length; ctr++) {
                if (list[ctr] !== unsorted[ctr]) {
                    rows += '<td class="affected">' + list[ctr];
                } else {
                    rows += '<td>' + list[ctr];
                }
            }

            anada.vars.$elements.push(rows);
        }
        increment = Math.floor(increment / 2);
        var row = '<tr>';
        anada.app.generateIterationList(list);

    }
    anada.app.generateTable('result-shell', 'Result of Shell Sort');
},
```

I tried following the answer below but I can't get it right, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would separate as far as possible the sort itself from the tracking. Do this by creating a generalised tracking object which :

- initially accepts the unsorted array, remembers it and prints it.
- as the sort iterates, accepts each partly sorted version of the array, compares it to the previous version and prints it with appropriate highlighting.

This approach will give two advantages :

- In the sort routine, the HTML-building will be reduced to one line - a simple function call
- The paradigm will be applicable to all sort algorithms.

### Edit

Here's some code :

```
PrinterComparitor: function(container) {
    var _arr, _container;
    var init = function(container) {
        _container = container.empty();
    };
    var printMessage = function(message) {
        var $tr = $("<tr/>").addClass('message').appendTo(_container);
        var $td = $("<td/>").text(message).appendTo($tr);
        $td.attr('colspan', length);
        setMessageSpans();
    };
    var setMessageSpans = function() {
        var $messages = _container.find(".message");
        var length = _container.find("tr").not($messages).filter(":last").find("td").length || 1;
        $messages.find("td").attr('colspan', length);
    };
    var print = function(arr) {
        var $tr = $("<tr/>").appendTo(_container);
        var $td;
        $.each(arr, function(i, val) {
            $td = $("<td/>").text(val).appendTo($tr);
            if(_arr && _arr[i] !== val) $td.addClass('affected');
        });
        _arr = $.extend(arr);
        setMessageSpans();
    };
    init(container);
    this.init = init;
    this.print = print;
    this.printMessage = printMessage;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4jnXf/3/)

Comment: Thank you for the thought. I might try that.

Comment: I updated my question and tried your thoughts, but I can't figure out what am I missing.

Comment: why not add a "location" variable to the object, set it to it's current index in the array before the sort. Sort the array. Then check if the object current index is equal to the stored value.